# ListView: onItemLongClick Toasts Object

Tags: android, android-listview, onlongclicklistener

I want to toast Text of selected list item in ListView. I'm using Custom Adapter. I tried this code.

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final int pos,
        final long id) {
    String text=String.valueOf(lv.getItemAtPosition(pos));
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

But it's Toasting Object name like `com.demo.CustomList@413ffb10`. Can anyone tell me how to Toast respective item?

**Note: The above code works for Simple Adapter,but not for Custom Adapter**

Comment: What you want to toast? Position of selected list item or Text of your selected list item?

Comment: I want to toast only Text.

Comment: post your custom adapetr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the list view has objects of the type CustomList as per your code it is displaying the default toString() method of your CutsomList class. You should instead access the variables that you would like to display and toast it.

For example:

```
       public class CustomList {
                  String title;

        public String getTitle(){
        return name;
        }
}
```

And in the onClick you can do the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,final int pos,
        final long id) {
     CustomList customList= (CustomList )lv.getItemAtPosition(pos);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), customList.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

This is exactly what you are looking for. Hope that helps.

Comment: How can I get ListView Items for CursorAdapter? This time I'm getting like android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41413280

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the structure of your `custom list view`. But if you want to `toast` `TextView` value from your `custom list view` then do something like this :

```
String text= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_LIST_ITEM_TEXT_VIEW).getText();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String text=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getItemAtPosition()` method returns an object belonging to the data structure the adapter works with, not an instance of the graphic widget